# Python unorderable types: function() > dict() in simple max(d, lambda...) call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda, max

I have a dictionary `d` like so:

```
d = {
    (1, 3): False,
    (4, 0): False,
    (0, 7): True
}
```

Now I want to get the highest `y` coordinate from the dictionary's keys:

```
h = max(d, lambda p: p[1])
```

But this raises an error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: function() > dict()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's more efficient to use `operator.itemgetter(1)` as your key function, rather than defining your own lambda expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `key` keyword.

```
h = max(d, key=lambda p: p[1])
```